# Throwing exception trying to cast NSSingleEntryDictionary to NSArray

Tags: json, swift

I am working in an iOS app that receives a JSON object to populate a table view.

Now I am facing a problem when the JSON response can not be cast to NSArray.

This is how I convert the JSON response to the needed array:

```
let directorioArray : NSArray  = json as! NSArray
```

This JSON response is the result of a search, and when there are no results, the response is :

```
{
    message = "No items found.";
}
```

And with this result, the app throws an exception:

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI' (0x1b33abd70) to 'NSArray' (0x1b33ac950)
```

How can I avoid this exception?

Comment: Don't use `NSArray` in Swift.

Comment: And please learn how to read JSON. Curly braces mean dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use native Swift array, and as suggested your Json return a dictionary.

**Try:**

```
if let directorioArray = json as? [String: Any] {
    //...
}
```

Comment: But the JSON in the question is a dictionary, not an array.

Comment: @rmaddy thank you, I suppose it was an array of dictionaries with only one entry. I will edit my answer.